# SQL: How to create 2 seperate values in a column for a single isnull scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm testing an SQL command as seen below:

```
with 
AllEvents AS 
           (
             SELECT E.EventName 
               FROM dbo.tblEvtDur E 
           GROUP BY E.EventName
           ), 
  EventDurations AS 
                   (
                    SELECT macstring, E.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, E.StartDT, E.EndDT)) 
                        AS DIFF 
                      FROM dbo.tblEvtDur E 
                Inner Join 
                          (
                           Select Distinct SUBSTRING(MacNm , 1,3) as MacString, MacID                 
                             From dbo.tblMachine)M on E.MacID = M.MacID  
                            Where E.DayID BETWEEN '20180501' 
                              And '20180531' 
                         Group By macstring, E.EventName
                           )

          Select MacString, AE.EventName, ISNULL(ED.DIFF,0) as DIFF 
            From AllEvents AE 
       Left Join EventDurations ED 
              On AE.EventName = ED.EventName 
        Order By EventName, MacString
```

The results I got can be seen here:

```
MacString   EventName   DIFF
NULL        BLK         0
COR         MDL         359880
FRA         MDL         1805253
COR         MTL         903783
FRA         MTL         324831
COR         OFF         6862901
FRA         OFF         9905131
COR         RPR         2986153
FRA         RPR         5799318
COR         RUN         7509506
FRA         RUN         11250157
```

Null is present because the EventName - BLK is not used within the DayID range. Now I want to make it so that the MacString will show 2 rows for 'COR' and 'FRA' when there is NULL value.

Like so:

```
MacString   EventName   DIFF
NULL        BLK         0
|
| (become)
v
COR         BLK         0
FRA         BLK         0
```

I tried using the ISNULL method to define the values if NULL is detected:

```
--modification in last row
   Select isnull(MacString, 'COR') 
       As MacString, AE.EventName, ISNULL(ED.DIFF,0) 
       As DIFF 
     From AllEvents AE 
Left Join EventDurations ED 
       On AE.EventName = ED.EventName 
 Order By EventName, macstring
```

But it seems to only allow for a single input. Is there any way to use ISNULL to create 2 rows with "COR' and 'FRA' in MacString column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `LEFT JOIN` on `NULL` value against a hard-coded list of `MacString`.

```
;with AllEvents AS 
(
    SELECT 
        E.EventName 
    FROM 
        dbo.tblEvtDur E 
    GROUP BY 
        E.EventName
), 
EventDurations AS 
(
    SELECT 
        macstring, 
        E.EventName, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, E.StartDT, E.EndDT)) AS DIFF 
    FROM 
        dbo.tblEvtDur E 
        Inner Join 
        (
            Select Distinct 
                SUBSTRING(MacNm , 1,3) as MacString, 
                MacID                 
            From 
                dbo.tblMachine
        )M on E.MacID = M.MacID  
    Where 
        E.DayID BETWEEN '20180501' And '20180531' 
    Group By 
        macstring, 
        E.EventName
),
NullMacStrings AS
(
    SELECT
        MacString = 'COR'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        MacString = 'FRA'
)
Select 
    MacString = ISNULL(ED.MacString, NM.MacString),
    AE.EventName, 
    ISNULL(ED.DIFF,0) as DIFF 
From 
    AllEvents AE 
    Left Join EventDurations ED On AE.EventName = ED.EventName
    LEFT JOIN NullMacStrings AS NM ON ED.MacString IS NULL
Order By 
    EventName, 
    MacString
```